# How can I see the execution time in JanusGraph by Gremlin in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

In JanusGraph, when any query is executed by Gremlin, how do you know the time it takes to execute the query?

Answer (score 1):

Gremlin has a `profile` step that will show you the time taken by each part or your query. For example you might do:

```java
g.V().has('team-name','Arsenal').profile()
```